# NSUserDefault NSString not getting displayed in label

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have a NSString that I use NSUserDefaults to store and move between multiple view controllers. The problem is, the NSString will not display in the label I am trying to show it in. Here is my code, I have no errors.

First View Controller:

```
 NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];

            NSString *score = @"message";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
             setObject:scoreString forKey:@"score"];
```

Second view Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Score"];  

    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"score"];
    savedValue = score.text;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I have no idea why the string is not getting displayed, the connections are all made. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> savedValue = score.text;

Your assignment is backwards. You're (uselessly) overwriting the variable holding the string you fetched from NSUserDefaults with the current value of the text field.

Comment: Haha thanks for bringing the excess code to my attention! Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
score.text = savedValue;
```

The following line is also not really doing anything:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Score"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in the second view controller, score is the name of your label?

If so, you should say

```
score.text = savedValue;
```